# How to update specific items in an array of objects is Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a doc in firebase representing a class in schoold, which has a list of object items including array of objects:

```
{{students: [{
          id: "xxx",
          name: "John",
          weight: "55",
          isPassed: false
        },
        {
          id: "xxx",
          name: "Marley",
          weight: "44",
          isPassed: false
        },
        {
          id: "xxx",
          name: "Beth",
          weight: "48",
          isPassed: false
        },
        {
          id: "xxx",
          name: "David",
          weight: "58",
          isPassed: true
        },
      ]
    },
teachers: {{...}},
name: "Tigers"
}
```

I am trying to update all items having `isPassed` key to `true`. I need something like:

```
await updateDoc(doc(db,"classes", class.id), { 
        "students.isPassed": true   // I know this synthax is wrong
      })
```

How is this possible?

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't possible with a single update.  You must read the document, make all the necessary changes to all the values in memory, then write the document field with the updated array.

Comment: @DougStevenson Ok, thanks this is brief and clear answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update all items having `isPassed` to `true`, you can change the `isPassed` inside a `map` function:

```
const classRef = doc(db, "classes", class.id);
const classSnapshot = await getDoc(classRef);

if (classSnapshot.exists()) {
 const classData = classSnapshot.data();
 const updatedStudents = classData.students.map(student => {
  if (!student.isPassed) {
   return { ...student, isPassed: true };
  }
  return student;
});

await updateDoc(classRef, { students: updatedStudents });
}
```